# How to get zero value when element is not present in data item

Tags: python

When I run the following code

```
for (x,y) in [(x,y) for x in Sites for y in Products] : 

    prob += (SupplyValue[(x,y)] + lpSum([vars[(i,j,k)] for (i,j,k) in TP if j==x  and k==y]) >=
             DemandValue[(x,y)] + lpSum([vars[(i,j,k)] for (i,j,k) in TP if i==x and k==y])), "Product Flow:%s %s" %(x,y)
```

I get error: `There is no entry with index(PL1, P1) for the data item "DemandValue".`

I want to get zero value whenever the entry is not available and continue with the loop. Much in the same way as iferror would do in excel.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `collections.defaultdict` for `DemandValue`.

```
In [1]: import collections

In [2]: DemandValue = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 0)

In [3]: DemandValue[0]
Out[3]: 0

In [4]: DemandValue[1]
Out[4]: 0

In [5]: DemandValue[0] = 12

In [6]: DemandValue[3] = 2

In [7]: DemandValue
Out[7]: defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x807ab0400>, {0: 12, 1: 0, 3: 2})

In [8]: DemandValue[7]
Out[8]: 0
```

**Update**: to re-use an existing dictionary:

```
In [1]: import collections

In [2]: normal = {1: 'foo', 'test': 'bar', (3,4): 17}

In [3]: d = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 0, normal)

In [4]: d
Out[4]: defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x807a90f28>, {1: 'foo', 'test': 'bar', (3, 4): 17})
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, when I put default value to demandvalue, i get error - "DemandValue" is a dictionary with 1500 items and so cannot be assigned a new dictionary value with 0 items. Is there a way around?

Comment: @AnkurGupta See updated answer. If that doesn't work, please edit your question and show *exactly* what you did and what error message you got.

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
     prob += (SupplyValue[(x,y)] + lpSum([vars[(i,j,k)] for (i,j,k) in TP if j==x  and k==y]) >=
     DemandValue[(x,y)] + lpSum([vars[(i,j,k)] for (i,j,k) in TP if i==x and k==y])), "Product Flow:%s %s" %(x,y)
except:
     pass
```

you can always just catch errors, and ignore them;)

**edit**: I hear you, this is a linear programming problem, and you do not want to restructure the loop adding a try/except in each iteration step, which my suggestion would require, sorry.

but still, I think the method is applicable .. sort of... :

```
def getDemandValue(x,y):
    try:
        return DemandValue[(x,y)]
    except:
        return 0
```

and

```
 prob += (SupplyValue[(x,y)] + lpSum([vars[(i,j,k)] for (i,j,k) in TP if j==x  and k==y]) >=
 getDemandValue[(x,y)] + lpSum([vars[(i,j,k)] for (i,j,k) in TP if i==x and k==y])), "Product Flow:%s %s" %(x,y)
```

Comment: Doing this will completely eliminate the equation. I only want to put demandvalue value as zero if key is not found.